# Convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^4\cos^2x}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to study the convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^4\cos^2x}dx$.I am not sure whether it converges or diverges.I am able to show only that $\frac{1}{1+x^4\cos^2x}\geq \frac{1}{1+x^4}$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$.But that does not give an bound for comparison test.So,can someone give me some hint for solving this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the integrand is always positive, we can write $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{1+x^4\cos^2 x} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\dfrac{dx}{1+x^4\cos^2 x}.$$ The original integral converges iff each of the integrals on the right side converge and the sum converges. Now, apply the bound $$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\dfrac{dx}{1+x^4\cos^2 x} \le \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\dfrac{dx}{1+(n\pi)^4\cos^2 x},$$ to each of the terms and see what you get.

Comment: Nice answer(+1). Why do we need the integrand be positive in order to breaking up the integral's interval?